# What is a good metaphor/analogy/idiom espousing the virtues of "developing something gradually over time"?

Tags: idioms, metaphors, popular-refrains

My question specifically relates to learning a new skill. Which could be used in the following example:

> An aspiring athlete trains for an hour each day without feeling like
>   she is making much progress. However....

One analogy that comes to mind, although not terribly elegant, is that if one adds a sufficient number of water drops to a bath tub, it will eventually fill.

Is there any folk here with a better example?

Comment: What would make another example better? There are countless ways of describing this situation, from dreadful clichés to purely original poetry. What are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of "**Rome wasn't built in a day**" immediately, but that is more of a cliché. Maybe you could try "**brick by brick**". I heard it used in the horse racing movie *Seabiscuit*. I see that "**inch by inch**" is another one similar.

I also thought about "**boiling a frog**" i.e. gradually, but that just made me laugh.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/brick+by+brick
https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/inch+by+inch
https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Rome+was+not+built+in+a+day
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling_frog

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one that I like very much, but it did not "belong" with my other answer. The "**day of small beginnings**" is a praiseworthy day.

> Do not despise the "**day of small beginnings**", for the Lord
>   rejoices to see the work begin.

Zechariah 4:10

Answer (score -1):

My late mother used to say 'It's like growing moss, it takes time.'